# Why is the second argument of the strtod function a non-const pointer?

Tags: c++, constants

I've tried to convert string to double using `atof` function. 
`double strtod (const char* str, char** endptr)`. It works fine, but why is `endptr` non-const? `**endptr` always points to `*endptr` and not to `endptr`.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking, why the parameter isn't a pointer to non-const pointer to const char?

Comment: I have something like this.
void foo(const std::string& str)
{
     .....
  const end = str.c_str();
  const double d = strtod(end, &end); //compile error
}

I don't want use const_cast.